# gradle wrapper build issue in flutter

Tags: flutter, gradle, dart

i am new to flutter. when i run my old flutter apps, they are running fine. but recently when i create new app on both vsCode and android studio by writing command `flutter run` on terminal, my app gets this error:

`'Test\my_test_app1\android\' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file. Error: Could not find or load main class org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain`

what might be the reason and how to fix. by the way i am using windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a directory path issue. Please make sure that you are running a `flutter run` command from the right directory path.

I think it should be from 'Test\my_test_app1' in place of 'Test\my_test_app1\android'

Comment: bro my terminal is on this `PS D:\Work\Fun & Test\my_test_app1>`. But after i run it says i am on `\android\`. But i am sure i am not running on that.

Comment: Yup space in the path can cause real problems. Especially if that is your users' folder. But it wasn't mentioned in question so I answered based on the information available. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue. Issue is occuring because in path(`D:\Work\Fun & Test\my_test_app1>` for my app there is `Fun & Test`. Because of space in my folder name, flutter can't find full path to my flutter app.